# how do I save custom prices to add on woocommerce (using woordpress) (script)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'll explain well I'm using woocommerce on my wordpress, I created a code that I'll show you below, I put it inside fucntion.php and a js called custom-fields.js.
As you can see in the image of the link that I attach here " [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UcpViy5yCWYMSbttx_ERdq0lEdUQvFMb/view?usp=sharing"](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UcpViy5yCWYMSbttx_ERdq0lEdUQvFMb/view?usp=sharing%22) each customer with email has different prices so the customer will have 3 euros of personalized price while the customer will have 2, 4 euros of personalized price.
This all works when I press the update button.
But when I refresh the page obviously the input boxes become empty, I would like the input boxes to remain completed so that next time I check and change the prices.
(I don't want to save them locally)
Can you help me?

```
PHP:
// Aggiungi una scheda personalizzata nella pagina del prodotto
add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_tabs', 'custom_product_data_tab');
function custom_product_data_tab($tabs) {
    $tabs['custom_tab'] = array(
        'label' => 'Personalizza Prezzo',
        'target' => 'custom_tab_content',
        'class' => array(),
    );
    return $tabs;
}

// Carica il tuo script JavaScript
function enqueue_custom_fields_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-fields', get_template_directory_uri() . '/custom-fields.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_fields_script');

// Contenuto della scheda personalizzata
add_action('woocommerce_product_data_panels', 'custom_product_data_fields');
function custom_product_data_fields() {
    global $post;

    echo '<div id="custom_tab_content" class="panel woocommerce_options_panel">';
    echo '<div class="options_group">';

    // Bottone per aggiungere campi personalizzati
    echo '<div id="custom-fields-container">';
    echo '<button id="add-custom-field" class="button">Aggiungi</button>';
    echo '</div>';

    // Contenitore per le input box aggiunte dinamicamente
    echo '<div id="custom-fields"></div>';

    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}

// Aggiungi l'azione per salvare i dati personalizzati quando si aggiorna il prodotto
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_custom_product_data');
function save_custom_product_data($post_id) {
    // Salva le email dei clienti
    $custom_emails = isset($_POST['_custom_email']) ? array_map('sanitize_text_field', $_POST['_custom_email']) : array();
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_custom_email', $custom_emails);

    // Salva i prezzi personalizzati corrispondenti alle email
    $custom_prices = isset($_POST['_custom_price']) ? array_map('sanitize_text_field', $_POST['_custom_price']) : array();

    // Assicurati che ci siano corrispondenze tra le email e i prezzi personalizzati
    if (count($custom_emails) === count($custom_prices)) {
        $email_price_mapping = array();

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($custom_emails); $i++) {
            $email = $custom_emails[$i];
            $price = $custom_prices[$i];

            // Se l'email e il prezzo sono validi, li associa
            if (!empty($email) && !empty($price)) {
                $email_price_mapping[$email] = $price;
            }
        }

        update_post_meta($post_id, '_custom_email_price_mapping', $email_price_mapping);
    }
}

// Sostituisci il prezzo di listino con il prezzo personalizzato
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'replace_list_price', 10, 2);
function replace_list_price($price, $product) {
    $custom_email_price_mapping = get_post_meta($product->get_id(), '_custom_email_price_mapping', true);

    if (!empty($custom_email_price_mapping)) {
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $user_email = $current_user->user_email;

        if (array_key_exists($user_email, $custom_email_price_mapping)) {
            return $custom_email_price_mapping[$user_email];
        }
    }

    return $price;
}


JS:

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    // Aggiungi un evento click al pulsante "Aggiungi"
    $("#add-custom-field").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Crea un nuovo input box per l'email
        var newInputEmail = $('<input type="text" name="_custom_email[]" placeholder="Inserisci l\'email del cliente">');
        
        // Crea un nuovo input box per il prezzo personalizzato
        var newInputPrice = $('<input type="text" name="_custom_price[]" placeholder="Inserisci il prezzo personalizzato">');

        // Aggiungi i nuovi input box al contenitore dei campi personalizzati
        $("#custom-fields").append(newInputEmail);
        $("#custom-fields").append(newInputPrice);
    });
});
```

Comment: Surely your code is responsible for populating those fields in the rendered page. If there is a default value that should be in those fields, then you populate the fields with their values, if there is an update to a value, then you populate the field with it upon refresh - as it would be done initially. Sorry, but I'm not sure why this question is being asking. \o/